# Check property value uniqueness in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Without enforcing a constraint, I would like to **check** for a property value uniqueness. I thought this would work:

```
MATCH (n:SomeLabel)
WHERE n.uuid IS NOT null
RETURN count(n.uuid) = count(DISTINCT n.uuids) AS is_unique
```

This returned `false` even though I know it's true. I then tried:

```
MATCH (n:SomeLabel)
WHERE n.uuid IS NOT null
RETURN count(n.uuid), count(DISTINCT n.uuids)
```

and discovered the second count is 0. How come?!
What's wrong with this query and would this be a good way to check uniqueness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it without duplicating the column, like this:

```
MATCH (c:Somelabel)
WHERE n.uuid IS NOT NULL 
WITH COUNT(c.uuid) AS uuidsCount, size(collect(distinct c.uuid)) AS distinctUuidCount 
RETURN uuidsCount = distinctUuidCount AS is_unique
```

Even this query worked on my system:

```
MATCH (c:Somelabel) 
WITH COUNT(c.uuid) AS uuidsCount, count(distinct c.uuid) AS distinctUuidCount 
RETURN uuidsCount = distinctUuidCount AS is_unique
```

Comment: Charchit - thank you for these better queries. Note I removed the part of your answer that blames the typo I had in the question, which I corrected as well. I still don't full understand why my original query doesn't work, but I can confirm it doesn't work also without the typo

Comment: Ohh that's strange. Ideally, they should have worked. I will try it on my system and get back, if I find anything

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
MATCH (n:SomeLabel)
WHERE n.uuid IS NOT null
WITH n.uuid AS p1, n.uuid AS p2
RETURN count(p1) = count(DISTINCT p2) AS is_unique
```

My guess is that aggregation functions, such as `count()`, consume the column, and so if you need multiple aggregation functions you need to first duplicate the column, as in the above. If someone would like to write a more elaborate explanation and perhaps even propose alternative (more efficient?) ways to check uniqueness, I'll be more than happy to give them the vote up and mark as answer.